# On a queue, which end is the "head"?

Tags: terminology

I had always thought that the "head" of a queue as the next element to be read, and never really questioned that usage. So a linked-list library I wrote, which is used for maintaining queues, codified that terminology: we have a `list1_head` macro that retrieves the first element; when using this library in a queue, this will be the first element to be removed.

But a new developer on the team was used to having queues implemented the other way around. He described a queue as behaving like a dog: you insert at the head, and remove at the tail. This is a clever enough description that I feel like his usage must be more widespread, and I don't have a similarly evocative description of my preferred usage.

So, I guess, there are two related questions: 1, what does the "head" of a queue mean to you? and 2, why do we use the word "head" to describe that concept?

Comment: "He described a queue as behaving like a dog"...Sounds like a fun guy to work with - Don't let him near a customer.

Comment: I don't know, but I would've guessed at your implementation, not the dog one.

Comment: Another good explanation about the difference between QUEUE and STACK:
[http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~mcw/cs367/lectures/stacks.html](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~mcw/cs367/lectures/stacks.html)

Comment: Also, in textbooks, the (singly) linked list is often introduced before other data structures like stack and queue, and then these are built on top of the linked list structure (which is not necessarily the preferred way to build these data structures today because of cache misses). A linked list will often have a head pointer (refers to the first element), and a tail pointer (to the last); in this arrangement, it is easy to insert at the tail end remove from the head - so, in a such a FIFO queue, you remove from the front. But note that this is really an internal implementation detail.

Comment: BTW, do think it's partially a language-related thing, but it's also about how we conceptualize what a queue does. To most people who know the meaning of the word "queue", or are introduced to the concept with that metaphor (waiting in line), the exit part is at the front/head; I suspect your friend conceptualizes it more like a pipeline kind of thing, where you push objects at one end (the start, or in some sense, the "head") of the pipe, and they exit at the other end.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You enter at the back of the queue, and leave from the front. In most societies, that would imply the head is the front, and items are removed from the head.

The [Javadoc for Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) seems to agree with the classic definition (i.e. your original one):

> Whatever the ordering used, the head of the queue is that element which would be removed by a call to remove() or poll(). In a FIFO queue, all new elements are inserted at the tail of the queue.

Comment: The C++ STL also agrees.

Comment: Also common terminology for FIFO / LIFO is to remove from the top of the Queue / Stack. The top of the dog is the head, not the tail. :-D

Comment: It seems that you've answered the 1st question, it really is commonly the case that the usage I'd understood is traditional... Thank you for the references. But it's not as iron-clad to me why the front of the queue is called the "head"...

Comment: ...so in which orifice of the dog do we enqueue items? ;)

Comment: When you're "ahead" of someone, you're in front of them, if no one is ahead of you, you *are* the head. This is the definition of head and ahead when it comes to placement.

Comment: The tail of a dog is the head of the queue.

Answer (score 8):

What people in the United States commonly call a line, as in the thing you stand in at the post office, people in other English speaking countries call a queue.  So, it's easier for Americans to keep the terminology straight if you substitute "line" for "queue."  In other words, when you are in the head, or front, of the line, you are the next to be called.

Comment: Maybe this is more a question about English, then, because the issue that seems to have come up is "why do we call the front the head?"

Comment: @AidanCully: because the head on a body is (in quadrupeds and other animals oriented horizontally) forward-facing, or the front.

Comment: That's the best possible explanation for us Americans.

Answer (score 5):

Both conventions are in common use. In my experience, when talking about queues in general, the head element is the next one to come out of the queue, and the tail is where elements enter the queue. This is consistent with everyday English usage—we get in line at the back, and the next to be served is at the front, or head. (And if you cut, it's to the back of the line for you!)

However, when a queue (aka FIFO) is implemented as a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), the terms are typically reversed, because the used portion of the ring buffer resembles a snake going around in a circle. Assuming the snake is moving forward, the head is naturally the end that leading the movement, which is also the end at which incoming items are inserted.

Comment: It's worth mentioning [circular buffers in the Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/circular-buffers.txt), which use the convention that items are added at the head, and removed at the tail.